# Prescient vs clairvoyant

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

What is the different between prescient and clairvoyant. And which would you consider George Orwell to be?

Comment: Have you looked these words up in a dictionary?

Comment: I would consider George Orwell to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

Prescient and clairvoyant are often considered synonymous. An individual is *a clairvoyant* if they posses the ability of clairvoyance. This is meant to be the ability to see mysterious things not available to the mundane, often things in the future. To be prescient is just to see the future in an unexpectedly accurate way.

Orwell would best be called Prescient in as much as his ability to see the future has no spiritual mystery to it, just historical knowledge. He experienced the world around him and predicted it would continue to deteriorate in understandable ways.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for explaining the distinction